# asp.net web api como hago para retornar un json con un identificador?

Tags: json, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Este el json que me bota la api, pero por defecto no tiene un identificador o llave.

```
[{"codigo":1,"nombres":"a","apellidos":"a"},{"codigo":2,"nombres":"b","apellidos":"b"},{"codigo":3,"nombres":"c","apellidos":"c"},{"codigo":4,"nombres":"d","apellidos":"d"}]
```

Como hago para que se muestre de esta manera.

```
["Usuarios":{"codigo":1,"nombres":"a","apellidos":"a"},{"codigo":2,"nombres":"b","apellidos":"b"},{"codigo":3,"nombres":"c","apellidos":"c"},{"codigo":4,"nombres":"d","apellidos":"d"}]
```

Estoy usando entity framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probablemente tengas tu controller de la siguiente forma:

[image: Controlador que retorna un arreglo de usuarios]

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un objeto que tenga un atributo de tipo **lista de usuarios** y que su propiedad (es decir la Key o "ID" como le llamas) sea **"Usuarios"**. Crea una clase (en la carpeta de Models) con el nombre "UsuariosResponse" y agrega el siguiente atributo:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace stack_278683.Models
{
    public class UsuariosResponse
    {
        public List<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Lo siguiente que tienes que realizar es modificar tu controlador donde devuelves los usuarios. Crea un objeto de tipo "UsuariosResponse" y asignale a su propieda "Usuarios" la lista de usuarios que obtenías previamente, no olvides agregar el metodo .ToList() a la línea db.Usuarios por que la línea de código **db.Usuarios**  devuelve un DbSet de tipo Usuario y el atributo del ServerResponse es de tipo List. El controlador te debe de quedar así:

```
// GET: api/Usuarios
    public UsuariosResponse GetUsuarios()
    {
        UsuariosResponse usuariosResponse = new UsuariosResponse();
        usuariosResponse.Usuarios = db.Usuarios.ToList();

        return usuariosResponse;
    }
```

Finalmente si haces una llamada al metodo api/Usuarios, te va a devolver esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Se uno de los héroes de la comunidad colocando código en lugar de imágenes que tiene código, las imágenes caen muy bien para representar errores principalmente, gracias por la comprensión :D buena respuesta por cierto.

Comment: Gracias , pero si quisiera digamos buscar un producto de ese usuarios o solo listar productos tendria que crear una clase Producto ? para poder colocar su llave ?